# Location of boards.txt for an Arduino DUE (SAM board)

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-due

I use the 1.6.7 Arduino IDE and I’ve installed the *"Arduino SAM Boards (32-bits ARM Cortex-M3)"* item for my DUE board, and it works fine.

However, I would like to tune some build parameters in my `boards.txt` file. **Problem**: I do not have a `INSTALL/hardware/arduino/sam` folder!
I do have the traditional `INSTALL/hardware/arduino/avr` folder, but in this one `boards.txt` does not contain the settings for the DUE.

- Where can the settings of the DUE be found?
- Should I create myself a new `boards.txt` file in a new `sam/` folder? What should be its default content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mystery folder can be found in the `Arduino15` directory, which is located under the **home folder** (not Arduino's install folder; that would be too easy). You can see the path in the Preferences (see below). The `boards.txt` file is in `Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.6`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Found my boards.txt for the esp32 here
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.11`

Answer (score 2):

It seems location changed at least in Linux, Eric Leibenguth answer still directs you to an arduino related folder but no boards.txt there.

Mine was at: `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/archlinux-arduino/avr/boards.txt`

you can find yours by enabling "Show verbose output during:" "compilation" in preferences and then in the logs it will show somewhere at the beginning something like:

```
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /usr/share/arduino/hardware/archlinux-arduino/avr
```

look around that path to find yours